# Runtime error in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am comparing two column D and E in my sheet which are containing Dates. 
The column E has date and sometime there are no Dates and sometime it has X, in the row. I  get an runtime error

> type mismatch

Could anyone suggest what is wrong with my code. ?

```
Sub datecompare()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long                 
    Dim Ztext As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Preparation Sheet")

    With ws
        lRow = .range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    
        For i = 2 To lRow
            zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", .range("E" & i).Value, .range("D" & i).Value)    
            If .range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .range("B" & i).Value <> "" And .range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"
            ElseIf .range("B" & i).Value = "" And .range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
                GoTo nextrow
            ElseIf zWeeks < 4 Then
                Ztext = " on time"
                zcolour = vbGreen
                Cells(i, 7) = "Green"
            ElseIf zWeeks > 8 Then
                Ztext = " delayed"
                zcolour = vbRed
                Cells(i, 7) = "Red"
            ElseIf zWeeks > 4 < 8 Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"
            End If

            With .range("F" & i)
                .Value = Ztext
                .Interior.Color = zcolour
            End With
nextrow:
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

The error occurs at 
`GoTo nextrow`

and it jumps to next, without running through the in between code.

Comment: because that's what you instructed the code to do, if the condition `ElseIf .range("B" & i).Value = "" And .range("E" & i).Value = "" Then` is met, then it goes straight to `nextrow:` at the bottom, and then straight to `Next i`. **BTW** all objects inside the `With ws` statement need to get the prefix `.` , like `Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"` should be `.Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"`

Comment: @ShaiRado ya , i agree, if the column B and E are empty, then it goes to next row. according to my code. When i researched on this run time error, it says there is a Chance of datatype being wrongly declared.Also, when i remove that X in the column E, then i dont find this error.

Comment: Are your column E  earlier days than column D?

Comment: in rare case , ya @ Dy.Lee

Comment: I think it should ble "zWeeks = DateDiff("ww",  .range("D" & i).Value,.range("E" & i).Value)  "

Comment: @Dy.Lee no the condtion is correct. the date which i am obtaining is from a database, so in somecase, there is a data and some case it is not there and few case it is X. since we have an data type of double for Zweeks, its getting type mismatch error. which says the data type should be changes. i am struck which data type to you, because i have date and X in column E.

Comment: @Mikz: Do you mean some of your data is not date value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147552/discussion-between-dy-lee-and-mikz).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the code woult to be like this.

```
Sub datecompare()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
    Dim Ztext As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Preparation Sheet")
    'Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lRow
            If IsDate(.Range("E" & i).Value) And IsDate(.Range("D" & i).Value) Then
            Else
                GoTo nextrow
            End If
            zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", .Range("E" & i).Value, .Range("D" & i).Value)
            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"

            Else '<~~ .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("E" & i).Value = ""  true or false , this is false
                If .Range("B" & i).Value = "" And .Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
                    GoTo nextrow
                Else '<~~ .Range("B" & i).Value = "" And .Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then  true or false, this is false
                    '<~~ When the result is false,  after code applied
                    If zWeeks < 4 Then
                        Ztext = " on time"
                        zcolour = vbGreen
                        Cells(i, 7) = "Green"
                    ElseIf zWeeks > 8 Then
                        Ztext = " delayed"
                        zcolour = vbRed
                        Cells(i, 7) = "Red"
                    ElseIf zWeeks >= 4 And zWeeks <= 8 Then
                        Ztext = "remaining"
                        zcolour = vbYellow
                        Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            With .Range("F" & i)
                .Value = Ztext
                .Interior.Color = zcolour
            End With
nextrow:
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Would you highlight the changes, their reason, and what was going wrong with the initial code??

Comment: @A.S.H: I'm new in English. So that is difficult for me.

Comment: @Dy.Lee the above suggested solution, dint resolve my problem'

Comment: @Mikz:  your  "ElseIf zWeeks > 4 < 8 Then"  occurrs error. It should be "ElseIf zWeeks >= 4 And zWeeks <= 8 Then".